# Why don't I get the right package variable when using our()?

Tags: perl

The below program prints "`var = 13`" and "`var = 13`". Shouldn't it print "`var = 3`" and "`var = 13`"?

```
use warnings;
use strict;

package p1;
our $var = 3;

package p2;
our $var = 13;
sub temp
{
    package p2;
    print "var = $var\n";
}

package p1;
print "var = $var\n"; #This prints var = 13. Why is it picking p2::var as the current package is p1?

&p2::temp;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the & sigil on your subroutine call?  I don't see any reason to override prototypes (there are none) or preserve the caller's @_ (there is no caller, and @_ is empty) when calling `p2::temp()`.  If this doesn't make sense, please read perlsub.

Comment: This is why our() should have never been a best practice.

Comment: @brain d foy Why do you say that?  I would say the problem is multiple packages in the same scope rather than a problem with `our`.

Answer (score 12):

From the first paragraph of [`perldoc -f our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html):

> `our` associates a simple name with a package variable in the current package for use within  the current scope. When use `strict 'vars'`  is in effect, our lets you use declared global
>   variables without qualifying them with package names, within the lexical scope of the `our` declaration. In this way our differs from `use vars` , which is package scoped.

Your first `our` creates an alias of `$p1::var` named `$var` in the current scope.  That scope runs until the end of the file (`package` statements do not create a new scope).  But then you create a new alias to `$var` (`$p2::var`).  So that alias lasts until the end of the scope (i.e. the file) or the next redefinition of the alias.

If you want to limit the scope of `our`, create a new scope:

```
#!/use/bin/perl

package p1;

use strict;
use warnings;

our $var = 3;

{
    package p2;

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    our $var = 13;
}

print "$var in package ", __PACKAGE__, "\n";

{
    package p2;

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    our $var;

    print "$var in package ", __PACKAGE__, "\n";
}

print "$var in package ", __PACKAGE__, "\n";
```

Comment: Limiting the scope of package statements is also a very good idea.

Comment: @daotoad: Agreed! I always try to use enclosing `{}` whenever using more than one `package` declaration in a single file (which I also try to avoid as much as possible).